# Generating Hexadecimal checksum for a NMEA (PMTK) message

Tags: gps

I am trying to use quectel L80 GPS receiver for my project. I am trying to configure the L80 using the PMTK strings. But the problem is the string should also contain a hexadecimal check sum.

eg. **$PMTK314,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0*29**

This is the example string given in the **"protocol specification"** document.
In this string '*29*' is the check sum. My question is how do I generate the checksum? I know that for NMEA strings, the check sum is generated by 'XOR' operation of consecutive characters between '$' and '*' . while calculating the check sum do I also need to include 'comma'?

Thanks

Comment: Oh thanks, its help full. :) The protocol specification does not include the information on how to generate the checksum.

Comment: @Roger I think on that page they're talking about the $ and * delimiters, the commas are included in NMEA checksums and you can see on that page if you include commas it changes the value.

Comment: Check out the Wikipedia page for NEMA Standard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just exclusive-or all the characters between the '$' and the '*' (including commas) and use the two-character hex representation of that byte (leading 0 if required to pad to two characters). Here's an example code fragment in Python:

```
st = "PMTK314,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"
i = 0
checksum = 0
while i < len(st):
   checksum ^= ord(st[i])
   i+= 1
print "%02X"%checksum
```

Result is 29

For "GPGSA,A,3,10,07,05,02,29,04,08,13,,,,,1.72,1.03,1.38", the result is 0A

Comment: This. Double-check it for known cases. As the specification and sample agree when you include the commas you have your answer.